# next js api returns no response after deployment

Tags: next.js, path, node.js-fs, next-api

while working on the local host, api and the posts.jaon file also works fine. was able to perform CRUD.But after I deploy it to vercel, the api does not loads.
error in the log is something like this:
`[GET] /api/insta 11:39:32:83 [Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open './posts.json'] { errno: -2, code: 'ENOENT', syscall: 'open', path: './posts.json' }`

expecting a json response  in the browser when I hit the api.

the json file is in the pages/api folder of next app.
I tried moving the json file outside pages at the top level of the folder strecture, and changing the path inside the fs("file.json",....). but nothing worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This article from Vercel might help you:

[How to Load Data from a File in Next.js](https://vercel.com/guides/loading-static-file-nextjs-api-route)

Here is an excerpt:

```js
import path from 'path';
import { promises as fs } from 'fs';

export default async function handler(req, res) {
  
  const jsonDirectory = path.join(process.cwd(), 'json');
  
  const fileContents = await fs.readFile(jsonDirectory + '/data.json', 'utf8');
  
  res.status(200).json(fileContents);
}
```

You would then have a folder named `json` where all the data is saved. That is declared in line 4. If you want to rename it, it is of course possible.

[image]